# Java Mockito Unit Testing - SPY nested HashMap

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a  nested method call where I need to `@Spy` a HashMap in the nested method calls. I just want to verify its size or contents, but its ***not*** being passed as a method argument ***nor*** is it a Class member field/property. My *concrete* **Classes** looks like this:

**// 1st method call from "MyClass" which declared using `@InjectMocks`**

```
 in UT
public class MyClass {

   public boolean method1(Arg arg1, int arg2) {
      Map<String, Object> inputMap = arg1.method2(arg2);

      return false;
}
```

**// 2nd nested method call which is returning the HashMap that I want** to be able to see the contents of in my UT

```
public class MyOtherClass {
   
   public Map<String, Object> method2(arg2) {
       Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();

      switch(arg2) {
      case 0: 
         map.put("key", new Object());
         break;
      default:
         break;
      }

      // some logic here
      return map;
}
```

**.....And my *Unit Test* (UT) looks something like this:**

```
public class MyClassTest {
   
   @InjectMocks
   private MyClass myClass;

   @Spy
   private Map<String, Object> inputMapSpy = new HashMap<>();

   
   @Test
   public void myUnitTestThatWillNotAllowMeToSpyTheNestedHashMap() {
       // stuff
       Arg arg1 = new Arg();

       myClass.method1(arg1, 5000);

       // every time inputMapSpy is 0, so its not getting "injected"
       assertTrue(inputMapSpy.size() == 10);
   }
```

Can anyone help me? Everytime as I said the `@Spy` of the Hashmap is never being used in the nested method calls so its size is always 0. Help!

Comment: The code presented does not compile, `return inputMap();` will result in a syntax error.

Comment: I dumbed down the code - is it because method2 wasn't instantiated or something?

Comment: No. it is because `inputMap` is a `Map` and we cannot use `()` on that. Even if we could, I am not sure what this would do. And I do not understand the overall setup. If the `Map` is ephemeral, and not used outside of the method, then why assert anything on it?

Comment: Can it be done at all? and it is somewhat of a "chokepoint" meaning that its a crucial nested method call that "prepares" that Map of data that will be used later.

Comment: @Turing85 I updated the code with better syntax, getting closer to the real nature of my code. Thanks so far for responding

Comment: Again: the code does not compile. Without a working example with clear intended behaviour, we cannot help.

Comment: Can you please tell me where the error is coming from?

Comment: I apologize; and I mean, what line or piece of syntax that I provided?

Comment: Please read my very first comment.

Comment: @Turing85 ah gotcha. Fixed that. Its just returning a boolean primitive

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect `@InjectMocks` to do, when `MyClass` doesn't seem to have any fields.  It looks like your `MyClass` object just doesn't know about your spied hash map.

Comment: The again:  I do not understand the overall setup. If the Map is ephemeral, and not used outside of the method, then why assert anything on it? Assert that the return value is what is expected and nothing else. Also, injection will not work since the map is created within the method.